# Does React automatically clear Intervals on unmount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting an interval on `componentDidMount`, storing the interval id returned, and using `clearInterval` on `componentWillUnmount`, and I'm wondering if this is necessary.

Is there a garbage collection type thing that would kill the interval anyway when the component unmounts? I know it would kill it on a hard refresh, but wondering about SPA.

Comment: There's no, because GC doesn't know if it should keep the interval or not

Comment: You have to clear it manually. You could abstract it into a HOC or even a custom hook if you find that you are repeating it in a lot of places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

By design, a `setInterval()` would never be cleared automatically (unless you write a custom function that handles this internally).

When you create an interval using `setInterval()`, you're essentially saying that you want to run a function at regular intervals regardless of the scope that the interval was created. Even if the interval was created in a scope that is no longer reachable from anywhere, the interval will still run as the lifespan of an interval has no dependency on the scope that it is running in.

For this reason, it's important to always clear intervals to prevent functions from piling up on every mount, which will lead to memory leaks and probably unexpected side effects as you'll have multiple functions running on an interval that are each doing the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

It is necessary to `clearInterval` on `componentDidUnmount`. With the introduction of hooks in React this tedious process of storing the interval in a member variable and later clearing it has been made a lot easier. You are now able to return a function in `useEffect` to clear created intervals like so:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => console.log("something"));

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

[Please refer to the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more information.

Comment: This will of course set a new interval on each render (you forgot the `[]`)

Answer (score -1):

I have not looked it up, but I don't think so. Because React has no way of knowing that you have initialised a setInterval. I would recommend that you clear it.